# Расстановка маркеров Google Maps по радиусу

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Начал разбираться с `Google Maps API`. Интересует расстановка маркеров в радиусе n-км от места пребывания.

Как реализовать? Может, дадите ссылки на ресурсы, примеры?

**Пример:**

Есть 100 маркеров, но чтобы на карту выводило только те, что в радиусе, например, 10-км.

Answer (score 1):

А в чем собственно проблема?

Вычисляешь текущее местоположение

```
  private GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener myLocationChangeListener = new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location l) {
            for(Marker marker:AllMarkers){
                if(CalculationDistance(marker.getPosition(),new LatLng(l.getLatitude(),l.getLongitude())) <10000)
                {
                    //рисуем marker маркер на карте
                }
            }
        }
    };

    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(myLocationChangeListener);

    public static double CalculationDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
        return CalculationDistanceByCoord(StartP.latitude, StartP.longitude, EndP.latitude, EndP.longitude);
    }

    private static double CalculationDistanceByCoord(double startPointLat,double startPointLon,double endPointLat,double endPointLon){
        float[] results = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(startPointLat, startPointLon, endPointLat, endPointLon, results);
        return results[0];
    }
```

Где AllMarkers это твоя коллекция с маркерами